# Retrieving key from new object created from create_object using Django generic views

Tags: django, google-app-engine, view, generics

My code looks as such:

```
def add_cart(request):
    return create_object(request, form_class=CartForm,
    post_save_redirect=reverse('test.views.show_cart',
                               kwargs=dict(object_id='%(key)s')))
```

Ideally, I would like it to look like so:

```
def add_cart(request):
    newobject = create_object(request, form_class=CartForm,
    post_save_redirect=reverse('test.views.show_cart',
                               kwargs=dict(object_id='%(key)s'))) 
    request.session['cartid'] = newobject.key
    return newobject
```

How can I retrieve the key from the newly created object?

I am using google-app-engine-patch with all the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

Under Django you can either use

```
newobject.id
```

or

```
newobject.pk
```

I recommend using *.pk*.

Remember that *newobject.pk* isn't always the same as *newobject.id*.

Answer (score 0):

The current generic views, create_object included, don't provide hooks to do extra processing with the created object.  So if you want to do this you'll have to roll your own create view, which really isn't very hard.

When Django 1.2 rolls around we should get class-based generic views, which will make it a lot easier to hook in extra bits of functionality.